# How to iterate a feature file on a JSON Array input with a condition check on all inputs?

Tags: api, automated-tests, cucumber, karate

I need to iterate my feature file with inputs from JSON Array but before every iteration, a condition needs to be checked and only if the condition passes, the iteration should occur.

Currently when I use the below syntax,

```
* def response = call read('createKitten.feature') kittenJsonArray
```

the feature file will be iterated for all JSON blocks in the array.

However is there a way to call the `createKitten.feature` only when `kittenJsonArray[i].name="Pooh"` in each iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just modify the `kittenJsonArray` (or create a new one) so that it contains only the values you need to process.

Use the [`karate.filter()` API](https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms). For example:

```
* def fun = function(x){ return x.name == 'Pooh' }
* def kittenJsonArray = karate.filter(kittenJsonArray, fun)
```